# RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS - Not fixed

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

Soo I am continuously getting this error after doing all available solutions here such as this one: [Error: RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427871/error-rnfirebase-core-module-was-not-found-natively-on-ios). I already followed that step by step. I updated my pod using pod update, installed my pods using pod install, all was successful but after running the app again with react-native run-ios, I still get that error after building. Do you guys have any idea as to why it doesn't get fixed?

*Edit*
This is the exact error I get from terminal:
[image]

Comment: Are you using flow?

Answer (score 1):

Thats really weird. I would try and do these things:

- Have you tried looking at your xcode project's: Target > Your app > Build Settings > Header Search Paths to check if there is something like this: `${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/Core/Sources` or similar, that is pointing to the `Firebase/Core`?
- Also, if that is already present, try and remove your `Podfile.lock` and/or `ios/Pods` and then run `pod install --repo-update` again.
- Also, if that does not work, try and remove the library from your `node_modules` by removing it from `package.json` and then running `yarn install` or `npm install` again. Then, remove all your `node_modules` path and run `yarn install` or `npm install` again. Then, add the `react-native-firebase` library, link it with react native, and reinstall the pods.

These are the steps I would try and do to fix it. I hope it helps you. :)

Comment: It still doesn't work :( I tried everything, I attached a screenshot of the exact build error I get from the terminal. Maybe there's something I missed?

Comment: @VinceGonzales Try and remove your `ios/build` path and then rebuild the app

Comment: i have fixed this issue by adding: ${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/Core/Sources in build settings.